# Armstrong's "Basic Topology" proof of Tietze Extension Theorem is wrong - what's the best fix?

Tags: general-topology

In Armstrong's "Basic Topology" he proves the Tietze Extension Theorem by first defining $d(x,A)$ (the distance from a point $x$ to a set $A$) as the infimum of a numbers $d(x,a)$ where $a\in A$.  He then proves a lemma saying $x\mapsto d(x,A)$ is continuous.  He then uses this lemma to prove the Tietze Extension Theorem (TET).

But in the proof of TET he applies the lemma in a case where it may be that $A=\emptyset$.  Clearly $d(x,A)$ is not a well defined real-valued function in that case.  But it's not completely trivial to fix the proof as far as I can see.  I can see ways to fix it, but I'm looking for the easiest way.  Is there a trivial work-around to fix this mistake in Armstrong's proof?  Thanks in advance for any insight.

Comment: If $A=\emptyset$, take the function $x\mapsto 0$ for all $x\in X$. This is continuous and extends the original function $f\colon A\to\mathbb R$, which is the empty function since $A$ is empty. (Assuming the $A$ you are talking about is indeed the closed subset of some topological space $X$, with a continuous mapping $A\to \mathbb R$, as in the statement of TET.)

Comment: Hmm, interesting, I actually think that works, not just in the lemmas that use it, but in the proof of Tietze too.  I had it stuck in my head that this distance must be infinity, since that's the inf of the empty set.  But making it one seems to fly.  I'll think it through carefully and post if I find any issues, but otherwise I think I'm happy with this answer.  Thank you!

Comment: Yes, no need to use this in the lemma. Simply add one line at the beginning of the proof: "If $A$ is empty, take a constant function. Let us assume now that $A$ is not empty. [...]"

Comment: Yes but the next lemma says given $A$ and $B$ closed disjoint, there is a continuous function that takes $1$ on $A$, $-1$ on $B$, and is strictly between $-1$ and $1$ on $(A\cup B)^c$.  That is needed in the proof of Tietze, where it could well be that $B$ is empty.  Since it is part of the induction step, it cannot be just handled as a special case at the beginning of the proof of Tietze.  So the lemma needs to apply to that case too.

Comment: This is Urysohn's lemma. Again, it is trivial if one of A or B is empty!